# HTML 5 Video Looping Issue (net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH)

Tags: php, apache, video, html5-video

One of our client's has a video that is suppose to play in an infinite loop, which was working fine until we updated the video. I am pretty sure that it has nothing to do with the code, which for the sake of the issue is the following:

```
<video style="background: #ffffff url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/homevid-2.jpg) no-repeat center; background-size:cover;" id="video-background" width="640" height="360" autoplay loop>
    <source src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/videos/homevid.mp4"  type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/videos/homevid.ogv"  type="video/ogg" />
```

When I analyze the network traffic, I notice two flags; One is a 206 partial content flag which I believe is normal in this situation (looping HTML5 video), and a second error ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH, which I know has to do with the content_length in the header being off. From here on I am not sure what to do. I do know that gzip is in equation!

Comment: HTTP 206 is not an error. It's stating the direct received content is only a part (it will be auto-set by the browser (at least in firefox) if the content is partial). Try to not compress the videos.

Comment: I tried this and no success.